# Android thread handler NullPointerException

Tags: android, multithreading

So this null pointer is confusing me. I believe it is a scope issue.

My main activity looks like this:

```
public class App extends Activity {  
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
  ProgressThread progressThread;
```

Then inside of the oncreate I do this:

```
  ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);  
  progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);  
  progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Images...");  
  ProgressThread progressThread = new ProgressThread(handler,mImageIds,mImages);  
  progressThread.start();    
  progressDialog.show();
```

THEN inside `progressThread` which is a separate class I do

```
mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage());
```

Now up until this point i believe it behaves as it should. I have my handler hanging out in class scope right underneath my oncreate

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {  
  public void handleMessage(Message msg){  
    progressDialog.hide();  
    progressThread.interrupt();  
  }  
 };
```

The program thinks that progressDialog and progressThread are declared, but are null. Why would they be null if I instantiate in my oncreate.

Comment: Btw, the progress dialog won't show until you exit oncreate(). Nothing can happen asynchronously in oncreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

and

```
ProgressThread progressThread = new ProgressThread(handler,mImageIds,mImages);
```

are both declaring local variables.  Change them to this:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressThread = new ProgressThread(handler,mImageIds,mImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before even starting to debug that, I would suggest using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. It was created for worker threads that need to report progress on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ian! I actually went ahead and reimplemented with AsyncTask. It is much cleaner and actually works better than it used to. Now I just need to implement a progressdialog with it.